# AfterUpdate in Access 2010 to populate textbox not working

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having some trouble populating text boxes with the After Update event.  My goal is to auto populate several text boxes in Access 2010 with the After Update event that takes empty or null fields and inserts either an NA for a string field or 0 for a number field. What I have done so far is to create a Handle Event then I call these from the After Update function.  Also, I have only tried this for the text box and not the form but I wasn't sure which to use as I am new to VBA.

The code works to populate the table linked to the field in the code using On Click and Key Press events when I go to the text box, however, my table does not automatically update when I use the After Update event after I go to another row. I can get it to work if I go to the text box and hit the space_bar or delete entries.  How do I get my table to automatically populate without clicking the textbox?

This is my handle event code:

```
Private Sub HandleEmptyStringEvent(object)
    If IsNull(object.Value) Or object.Value = "" Then
        object.Value = "NA"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub HandleEmptyNumberEvent(object)
    If IsNull(object.Value) Or object.Value = "" Then
        object.Value = 0
    End If
 End Sub
```

Then it gets called with:

```
Private Sub Field1_AfterUpdate()
    HandleEmptyStringEvent Me.Field1
End Sub

Private Sub Field2_AfterUpdate()
    HandleEmptyNumberEvent Me.Field2
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: No Field is just a generic term to keep my real data private. I modified my code to change the field names.

Comment: No error message, it is just not working the way I want it to work. I edited my question with more info and clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at this my first instinct is that "After update" is not a good event to trigger this code. - If you are looking for null fields the only way this would trigger is if the field had something in it then you deleted it. After update needs a change in value to trigger it (or else it does not update the value). On exit would be a better option for you to trigger your code.

Comment: I changed the AfterUpdate to Exit(Cancel As Integer) keeping the rest of the code as is, but it still did not work. Am I missing something in the code?

Comment: I just tested the code that you have and it works fine. You will want to delete the previous code that was listed on after update. Then add a new event from the property sheet and paste the code there, but i'm  guessing that is what you did. you can also solve this by using: If IsNull([Field1]) Then
[Field1] = "NA"
End If, but your method should be easier with more fields.